# objective-c filter table view with data from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've based my code from [this](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-searchbar-to-tableview) example.  The initial data is shown in the table view but I'm not sure how to implement the rest to display the filtered data.  I have no errors, search bar works but no filtered data.  Here's my plist XML:

```
<dict>
    <key>Things to do</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>activity</key>
            <string>Watch movies or TV shows</string>
            <key>keywords</key>
            <array>
                <string>tv shows</string>
                <string>movies</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>activity</key>
            <string>Go Hiking</string>
            <key>keywords</key>
            <array>
                <string>hiking</string>
                <string>mountains</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>activity</key>
            <string>Video Games</string>
            <key>keywords</key>
            <array>
                <string>video games</string>
                <string>playstation</string>
                <string>xbox</string>
                <string>nintendo</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Here is my CategoriesViewController.m:

```
@interface CategoriesViewController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categories" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *categoriesDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

self.tableData = categoriesDictionary[@"Things to do"];
//I think this next line is supposed to make it appear on top of the original table
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.tableData count]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row][@"activity"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{   
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
    searchText];

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
    scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
    objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
    selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}
```

It's just like the example except I changed where my data is coming from.  How can I search based on the keywords?  In this example, am I only searching what is contained in my initial table view?  Thanks for your time...

Comment: where u actually reloading the tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard tell without more code, but I think you'll need to show/hide your two table views based on the search string.

If the string is empty, this will hid your `searchResultsTableView` and show your other table view which I'm I'm lovingly calling `whatEverYouCalledYourOtherTableView`.

If your string is not empty you do your search, show `searchResultsTableView`, hide `whatEverYouCalledYourOtherTableView` and reload the data for `searchResultsTableView`.

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    if ([searchString isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
        self.searchDisplayController.whatEverYouCalledYourOtherTableView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                                   scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                           objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];


        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = NO;
        self.searchDisplayController.whatEverYouCalledYourOtherTableView.hidden = YES;
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Also your `filterContentForSearchText` is wrong. You have an array of dictionaries not strings.  First grab just the strings, then run your search. You'd be better off creating a dictionary of strings right away, the simplest way of getting your search to work is like this.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{   
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];

    NSMutableArray *activityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableData count]; i++)
    {
        [activityArray addObject:self.tableData[i][@"activity"]];
    }

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[activityArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}
```

Comment: I think based on this example, the filtered table is supposed to show on top of the original one.  I'll update my code, can you see if that makes the difference?

Comment: I haven't looked through the example, but I think the idea is you have both tables in the same spot, but of course only one showing at a time.  So when the user searches (or clears the search) you need to hide one and show the other, then of course reload data for you searching table.  The full list doesn't change, so there should be no need to reload the data.  Make sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  I guess I'll have to rewrite the code.  Based on the code that I added, there's no fix here?

Comment: You are on the right track I think. Make sure your UITableViews set `CategoriesViewController` as their data source and as their delegate.

Comment: When I log the NSPredicate *resultPredicate, I get the letters that I'm typing.  When I log the searchResults, I get ().  Can you check to see why filteredArrayUsingPredicate isn't comparing the data and setting a new array?

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I actually figured I had to do something like that because it had no idea what to compare to.  I also had to delete forIndexPath:indexPath in the dequeReusable...otherwise it was crashing my app...saying 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'...any idea why that is?  In layman's terms :)

Comment: Yeah, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` will not return a nil cell, but first you must tell it what kind of cell to return.  In your case just a `UITableViewCell`.  You need to call this first `[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];` typically where you define the UITableView, but could be done just before the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:`.

Comment: Ok that worked.  Moving on to another question...how to compare my search results with the original tableData and get the rest of the data?  I'm coming from php so working with objective c arrays and their syntax is really confusing me.  I'm going to post a question soon, if you could look it over I'll be very grateful